# What does this perl replace string do?

Tags: regex, perl

I have no idea what is going on here ... I am trying to manually do this rather than have Perl do it.

```
my $replace_string
    = "s/typedef struct WebFontDescription WebFontDescription/struct WebFontDescription/g";

print $fh "perl -p -i -e \""
        . $replace_string
        . "\" \""
        . $idl_filename
        . "\"\r\n";

$replace_string
    = "s/\(WebFontDescription\\* webFontDescription/\(struct WebFontDescription\\* webFontDescription/g";

print $fh "perl -p -i -e \""
        . $replace_string
        . "\" \""
        . $idl_filename
        . "\"\r\n";
```

I see that it looks for a string

`typedef struct WebFontDescription WebFontDescription`

and then replaces it with

`s/\(WebFontDescription\\* webFontDescription/\(struct WebFontDescription\\* webFontDescription/g`

but how do you replace a regex with a regex? That doesn't make any sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It creates the following pair of shell commands:

```
perl -p -i -e "s/typedef struct WebFontDescription WebFontDescription/struct WebFontDescription/g" "file"
perl -p -i -e "s/(WebFontDescription\* webFontDescription/(struct WebFontDescription\* webFontDescription/g" "file"
```

---

The first one replaces every instance of

```
typedef struct WebFontDescription WebFontDescription
```

with

```
struct WebFontDescription
```

---

The second doesn't do anything but throw an error message because it doesn't compile. (Unmatched `(`.)

Comment: It's like inception. A script in a script.

Comment: @squiguy, And very poorly done at that. `String::ShellQuote`'s `shell_quote` should be used in there.

Comment: presumably the `\(` was supposed to be `\\(`

Comment: doesn't clobber the file; the file never even gets opened

Comment: @ysth, Oh yeah, the file is just opened the first time you read from ARGV. Fixed.